Which way is SPSS Fisher's Exact 1-sided Test reading my 2x2 Table?
I ran a 2x2 Chi-Square test in SPSS and have a significant result for the 1 Sided Fisher's Exact Test.




High
Not High




Group A
8
11


Group B
2
15



Fisher's Exact Test : Exact Sig (2-Sided) = .065
Fisher's Exact Test : Exact Sig (1-Sided) = .047
I understand that the 1-Sided result means that only one direction is significant. But I don't know which direction that is. Hoping someone can help me interpret what the 1-sided significance means for my example.
